# How to remove scrollbar from iFrame (Typeform)

Tags: iframe, scrollbar

Tried adding overflow hidden but no luck.

I still want it to scroll, but without the scrollbar at the side.

Here's a link to my page with the iframe on there.

http://www.customlogoshop.com/order-2

Here is my code

```html
<iframe id="my_typeform" src="http://luke185.typeform.com/to/tF7baL"style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>
```

Comment: Am I able to change the css of the iframe?

Comment: Hey @luke-hall, got any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just worked out a way to do this and I thought I would share this with you as no one has answered your question. The solution that worked best for me was to apply an absolutely positioned div on the .typeform-widget class like so:

```
.typeform-widget:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF;
    left: 94%;
}
```

as I am embedding a typeform form into a white page positioning an absolute white div over the top of the default scroll bar worked the best out of the solution I have tried today - hope that helps.

Comment: nice hack, thanks. To get it working with the current embed code from Typeform, use the selector .typeform-widget-wrapper:before